# javascript reading an object as parameter of a function

Tags: javascript, object

Im making a kind of template for all usual mouse events in canvas.
so we have a class to define words, and all events must be launched when mouse is over the word.
then I´d declared a test object (pal) in the "universal" ( but now enclosed in a spacename) part of the code.
the function `contains(pal)`uses this test object declared as parameter, however the console saids *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'posX' of undefined at contains"*
as posX is an object "pal" atribute, the function contains(pal) cannot read this object I gess.
the question is ... why?
see the complete code at https://jsfiddle.net/evy182bp/

Comment: Code you linked don't work `Uncaught ReferenceError: plantillaEventos is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the line 141 is the one that causes the issue

```
 console.log( "pincha dentro = ", contains());
```

Issue is that you call the contains method without passing a parameter of pal object, meaning that it automatically passes 'undefined' (take a look [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c))

```
function contains(pal) {

  if((pal.posX <= mouse.x)&&
  (pal.posX + pal.largoPalabra >= mouse.x)&&
  (pal.posY <= mouse.y)&&
  (pal.posY + pal.altoPalabra>= mouse.y))
  {return true;}
  else { return false;}
  // if ((100 <= mouse.x)&&
  // (100 + 150 >= mouse.x)&&
  // (200 <= mouse.y)&&
  // (200 + 40>= mouse.y)) // this works
}
```

As soon as you remove that line, you are without errors.
Hope this helps